# Do `<img>` that are smaller than the original still load the entire image file?

Tags: html, image, jpeg

When I have an `<img>` that is smaller than the original image, will the file automatically be resized? Or will the user have to load the entire image?

For example, I have giant wallpaper files, but I only show thumbnails that are 100px by 100px. Am I doing something inefficiently by just setting the `<img>` width and height to 100px?

Comment: Yes you have to load the whole image even if you set the `img` to 1x1 px

Comment: Read this: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#ScaleImages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The browser has to download the entire image file and then scale it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, whole image will load and then scaling will be there.

Why don't you search before asking a simple question.
If you google it you can easily get this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next time please do some Google and practice it on any editor before you ask any questions that will give you hands on experience.

Answer :- Whole image will be loaded and whole image will be automatically re-sized, Yes it is not good practice to use big amount of size to small scale of image height and width